# Matlab cubic spline interpolation based on data points-first point and last point are connected?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data using csape(t, x); but the first data point is always connected to the last data point for each segment.

For example: If I want to interpolate a J curve, it gives me a close O.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you try using `interp1` with the `spline` tag?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#btwp6lt-2_1.  This doesn't close the first and last points together.  Do you have to use `csape`?

Comment: You can also use `spline` if you want more control about the conditions of the cubic spline interpolation you are performing in between the control points, as well as the first and last control point conditions: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html